# How create separate DataBase for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3 and want whenever user will be created, then separate Data Base should be created for newly created user.

e.g if I have 13 migration in my application,  so 13 tables should be created for newly created user.

How I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: I wouldn't recommand that you do this. It will make scalability very hard when you have a lot of users. And your deployments (with migrations) will be very long.

Comment: But my requirement is this whenever new customer is created New DB should be create and all data related to this user should be inserted in its DB.And customer is role of user also with admin and super admin

Comment: `https://github.com/kovyrin/db-charmer` may help. However, this is almost certainly a bad idea. Perhaps you could give more reasoning behind your requirements?

Comment: Check out @jeg2's presentation from railsconf. https://speakerdeck.com/u/jeg2/p/10-things-you-didnt-know-rails-could-do slides 21 and forward details how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also check out the audio/video that goes along with James slides here http://www.confreaks.com/videos/889-railsconf2012-ten-things-you-didn-t-know-rails-could-do. Move forward to around 15:30 for the section on one user per database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea to handle many DB in Rails!

You can add a field, say, `user_id` in each of your tables that are needed to be separated and then apply `default_scope` to their respective models (or make an abstract model with `default_scope` via `self.abstract_class = true` and inherit your "shareable" models from it).

Your `default_scope`, as you might guess, should look like:

```
default_scope lambda { where(user_id: current_user_id) }
```

How to get the current user, you may ask?

Models can't access `session`, so you can make the following "hack" in order your scope to work:

```
#in ApplicationController
before_filter do
    user_id = session[:user_id]
    ActiveRecord::Base.class.send :define_method, :current_user_id, lambda { user_id }
end
```

I guess you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is best post i follow and solve my problem

```
 http://7fff.com/2010/12/02/activerecord-dropcreate-database-run-migrations-outside-of-rails/
```